# how could I build android 4.4.4_r1 for Nexus 5x

Tags: android, nexus-5x

I did a lot of research, but all posts are using repo to build android, and there're no android 4.4 version branch for Nexus 5x from google website.

So, can we build android 4.4 to Nexus 5x?

How to build the drivers for android 4.4 on 5x?

Anyone with any clue?

Comment: that's because there was never Android 4.4.4 for 5x. It was released with Android 6.

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko Yes, I'm aware of that. So I'm asking for help for some advice whether anyone did this before or is it gonna work or not.

Comment: I'm sure that nobody did, at least because I never heard anybody doing versions older than the device-release version. It does not make any sense to do that. Why do you want to do that anyway?

Comment: Hi @VladyslavMatviienko, I did a lot of search, and find nothing about this. Maybe buying a corresponding device is better saving time. I want to do this to test some software, but, I guess I'm going to give this up. Thank you for your comments.

Comment: I'd suggest you to try the emulator. Depending on the functions you want to test, it could be enough for testing.